# Upload a jpg image, resize it, then convert it to base64 with a mime of image/jpg

Tags: javascript, base64, png, jpeg

I've been working on doing this, so far I have a working code, but it outputs the image to base64 as a image/png. Is there a way to set the canvas to jpg instead?

This code I assembled from multiple posts thanks from the help of you guys here on StackOverflow

here is my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
   #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
  </style>
  </head>
   <body>
  <input type="file" id="input"/>
   <br>
      <canvas id="canvas" width=800 height=600></canvas>
         <script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
        var cw=canvas.width;
        var ch=canvas.height;


        var maxW=320;
        var maxH=200;

        var input = document.getElementById('input');
        input.addEventListener('change', handleFiles);

       function handleFiles(e) {
          var img = new Image;
       img.onload = function() {
           var iw=img.width;
           var ih=img.height;
           var scale=Math.min((maxW/iw),(maxH/ih));
           var iwScaled=iw*scale;
           var ihScaled=ih*scale;
           canvas.width=iwScaled;
           canvas.height=ihScaled;
           ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,iwScaled,ihScaled);
           document.getElementById("base").value=canvas.toDataURL();
       }
     img.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
       }
    </script>
   <textarea  cols="80" rows="50" id="base" name="img"></textarea>

   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: um, Java or JavaScript? Your question is tagged "Java" but yet you are showing JavaScript code. Please take care with tagging since you don't want the wrong experts going to your question.

Comment: sorry about that. I'm kind of new when it comes to java terminology. I guess java comes in all kinds of flavors.

Comment: ?No, not even close. Java and JavaScript are completely different languages, about as close as ham is to hamburger.

Comment: well they shouldn't do that. It makes it confusing.  Its such a bad form in the world to confuse people with products  "A" , "B" & "C"  having the same or similar name.

Answer (score 0):

well I've been fiddling with it some more and changing this gets me image/jpeg to show up in the base64 code. What is strange is that it will still try to save as a png when I change the textarea tag to an img tag and also changing the element id in the script from "value" to "src" on this line:

```
 document.getElementById("base").value=canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
```

adding the "image/jpeg" lowered the png file by 5K (compared to the other png) but is this correct? should it try to save to jpg?

or is it a default in the browser, and I have to pass a mime type to the img tag somehow....